# Unable to load response for 500 internal server error in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have call from UI to backend. Backend will throw 500 internal server error and some validations if any and I have to show them in the front end. Here is a sample image of it in firefox.[Firefox](http://i62.tinypic.com/2en3zh4.png)

But in chrome for the same call I am unable to receive any response. I do not think that it is a backend issue as the call is working in firefox. My question is, is there something wrong with my call? Am I missing something that has to be added specifically to an ajax call in chrome? Here is the image from chrome.[Chrome issue](http://tinypic.com/r/30cocom/8)

Here is the call.

```
        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: requestUrl,
                data:data,
                async : ajaxHeaders.async,
                success: function(response) {
                    options && options.success && options.success(response);
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    options && options.error && options.error(response);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Are you manually throwing 500 error?

Comment: Yes. Throwing an exception manually in the backend (Spring MVC)

Comment: Why not just return JSON with some error key inside?

Comment: The server is returning JSON and I am able to see it  and use it in firefox. The issue arises only with Chrome

Comment: Maybe Chrome gets error response (header) and ignores any output?

Comment: I am sorry. I am unable to understand what you mean by output. Can be more detailed. I am a beginner. What do you mean by output?

Comment: You don't have to throw exception for Ajax to understand that something is wrong. Just return something like `{"error":"Error message"}` and in `success` check `if (json['error']) {` to define if error occurs.

Comment: No offense, but isn't what you are saying a workaround? I do not understand what the actual problem is. Also I am using Backbone model save in most of the application. The same problems arises there too. In that case, I cannot check for error in success. Also, changing close to hundred calls in the entire application will be tedious process.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out the problem. 
There's an issue with chrome. If the chunked response does not end properly chrome cannot read it. But, firefox and safari are taking care of this internally.

So solution will be in the backend to send the chunked response properly. Spring MVC has this bug. What we can do is to send response manually by appending the response body we want.